# Removing data from Array once pulled from AD

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm currently pulling user data from Ad by OU, then updating certain fields, which works fine.
I want to modify the script to only update certain users but struggling, to remove any of the entries from the array as it is a fixed size. I converted to ArrayList and can get count of object, and can query then individually etc..

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DN" -Properties GivenName, Surname,mail,UserPrincipalName,SAMAccountName,proxyAddresses | Select GivenName, Surname,mail,UserPrincipalName,SAMAccountName,proxyAddresses 

$WorkingSet =[System.Collections.ArrayList]($users)
```

`$WorkingSet.count`  gives *47* as result with last element being:

GivenName: Laura
Surname:Willox
mail:WilloxL@domain
UserPrincipalName :Laura.Willox@domain
SAMAccountName    : Laura.Willox
proxyAddresses    : {smtp:laura.willox@domain, SMTP:WilloxL@domain}

but trying  `$WorkingSet.IndexOf('Laura.Willox')` gives *-1*  instead of *46*
So then I can't do something like `$WorkingSet.RemoveAt($WorkingSet.IndexOf('Laura.Willox'))`

Is something about this data that I am not understanding,that it can't be queried like this?

Comment: You're looking for the `Where-Object` cmdlet: `$usersMinusLauraWillox = $users |Where-Object SAMAccountName -notlike 'Laura.Willox'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely do not need to wrap your data in an `ArrayList`, it'll only complicate your code unnecessarily.

Instead of trying to modify the output from `Get-ADUser` inline in a list, use PowerShell's `Where-Object` cmdlet to *filter* the data:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DN" -Properties GivenName, Surname,mail,UserPrincipalName,SAMAccountName,proxyAddresses | Select GivenName, Surname,mail,UserPrincipalName,SAMAccountName,proxyAddresses 

# use `Where-Object` to filter the data based on individual property values
$usersSansLaura = $users |Where-Object SAMAccountName -ne 'Laura.Willox'
```

Here, we pipe any user objects contained in `$users` to `Where-Object SAMAccountName -ne 'Laura.Willox'` - the `-ne` operator is the "**n**ot **e**qual" operator, so the output will be any input object that *does not have a `SAMAccountName` property with the exact value `Laura.Willox`*, and then assign those to `$usersSansLaura`

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71831449/45375) is worth considering:

- In PowerShell, it is unusual to directly manipulate resizable collections.
- Instead, collection processing in PowerShell usually involves creating *new* collections by *filtering* the original collection, using the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) in the pipeline or, for collections already in memory, the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where).

If you do need to deal with in-place resizing of a list data type, I suggest using [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) instead, whose `.FindIndex()` method allows you to do what you wanted:

```sh
# Note: I'm using [object] as the type parameter for simplicity, but you 
#       could use [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser] for strict typing.
$WorkingSet = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new(
  @(Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DN" -Properties GivenName, Surname,mail,UserPrincipalName,SAMAccountName,proxyAddresses | Select GivenName, Surname,mail,UserPrincipalName,SAMAccountName,proxyAddresses)
)

# Find the index of the user with a given SAMAccountName: 
$ndx = $WorkingSet.FindIndex({ $args[0].SAMAccountName -eq 'Laura.Willox' })

# If found, remove the user from the list
# (-1 indicates that no matching element was found)
if ($ndx -ne -1) {
  $WorkingSet.RemoveAt($ndx)
}
```

Generally, note that both [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) and `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 `` have a `.Remove()` method that allows you to pass the *object* (element) to remove directly, irrespective of its index.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Since your array list is composed of `ADUser` instances, the `.IndexOf()` method requires passing *such an instance* in order to locate it among the elements - you can't just pass a *string* referring to one of the *properties* among the elements.

Instead, you need a *predicate* (a Boolean test) that compares the string to the property of interest (`.SamAccountName`), which is what the `.FindIndex()` call above does.